# Simple font size changer with Material UI slider and React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, slider

I'm trying to make a simple slider that change the font size using React and Material UI.
The slider is called PrettoSlider and it a part of Material UI.

What im trying to acheive is to use the slider an then change the font size depending on the slider.
This is what i have so far

```
export default function ChangeFontSlider() {

  const [ItemValue, setItemValue] = React.useState(20);

const handlingChange = (event) => {
   setItemValue(event.target.value);
   event.preventDefault();
}
return (
    <>
      <p style={{fontSize: {ItemValue}}}>Drag me to change the font</p>
      <PrettoSlider 
      onChange={handlingChange}
      value={ItemValue}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

When trying to slide the slider, I ether get an error or the font remain the same.
Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Missing info here. What is `PrettoSlider`? I can't find that in MUI anywhere, is it it just a styled MUI slider? Also what **specific** error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

> The slider is called PrettoSlider and it a part of Material UI.

PrettoSlider is an example. Underline component is Slider which is documented here https://material-ui.com/api/slider/.

[image]

Accroding to the document, onChange function has 2 parameters, `event` is the event source while second parameter `value` is new value when you move slider, is what you need to get data from.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 8 months old, But you could also just do this in your style tag

```
 <p style={{fontSize: `${ItemValue}px` }}>Drag me to change the font</p>
```

then instead of just updating a number every time you slide, it will actually increment in pixels

Answer (score 0):

in **mui** for change the font of slider label you can use **global class** in slider api.

```
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";

const sliderStyles= makeStyles({
  slider: {
    '& .MuiSlider-markLabel' : {fontFamily: 'Vazir' , fontSize: "12px"}
  }
})
```

and set this class to className prop in slider.

```
import { sliderStyles} from "YOUR/STYLES/PATH";
<Slider
     valueLabelFormat={valueLabelFormat}
     getAriaValueText={valuetext}
     step={null}
     valueLabelDisplay="on"
     marks={sliderMarks}
     className={classes.slider} //this line important
 />
```